# best practice for return value in WCF services

Tags: wcf, service, return-value, cloud

I have a WCF service sitting in the cloud.
And my application makes several calls to this WCF service.
Is it a best practise:
1]  to always use return value as bool which indicates if the operation was sucessful or not.
2] returning the values you meant to return as the OUT parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

- return an atomic value (bool, string, int) if appropriate
- return a complex type (a class instance) if I need to return more than one value - make sure to mark that class with `[DataContract]` and its properties with `[DataMember]`
- a SOAP fault `FaultException<T>` when an error occurs; the `<T>` part allows you to define your own custom error classes, and again - don't forget to mark them with `[DataContract] / [DataMember]` and declare them as `FaultContract` on your operations

Answer (score 0):

1] to always use return value as bool which indicates if the operation was sucessful or not

- Yes, if the operation isn´t time consuming AND the return status is always relevant:
  Waiting on a return value can affect both client and service host(server) performance/scalability. Ex. in a Request-Responsecall, Requests can keep connections open for a long preriod of time waiting for operation completion. You could implement in a way similar to "HTTP 202 Accepted" status code usage(i.e operation received arguments and has started(patially), but does wait for the completion)
- No, if the operation logic only makes sense if synchronous.
- No, if you are keen on refactorability/maintainability ex. when you want to return include an error message/code in the return.

2] returning the values you meant to return as the OUT parameters

- Yes, this makes the service operation more wsdl compliant and easy to read.